# Most efficient way to call/access windows form controls in a class

Tags: c#

I added a CSharp Class to a form project. Now I want to access the form controls from the Class.

I am using this piece of code with the implicit var as follows:

```
var form = frmClasses.ActiveForm as frmClasses;
```

Using this code, I set the form Modifiers to public, place the code is a method/function and I am able to access the form controls in the class.

The problem is each time I need to call a form control I have to use the var and the entire line of code above. Is there a simpler way that is less redundant?
Example: Each method/function in a the class will need to call the form controls thus referencing the form controls using Var.

Take a look at the code below, you will noticed that I am using Var to call each form control.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Classes
{
    class ClsProperties
    {   
        //VALIDATE TEXTBOX
        public static void validateTextBox()
        {
            var form = frmClasses.ActiveForm as frmClasses;
            if (form.txtMyTextBox.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                form.txtMyTextBox.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
            }

        }

        //VALIDATE RADIO BUTTON
        public static void validateRadio()
        {   
            var form = frmClasses.ActiveForm as frmClasses;
            if (form.radBtnColor.Checked == false)
            {
                form.lblShowError.ForeColor = Color.Aquamarine;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Form Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Classes
{
    public partial class frmClasses : Form
    {
        public frmClasses()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClsProperties.validateRadio();
            ClsProperties.validateTextBox();
        }
    }
}
```

I could put all the validation in one method but I am simply trying to show how I would call multiple methods using a class.

Is there a better way to access the form elements in a class?

Merci

Comment: Do you want to do type assertion? Try referencing to it like `((frmClasses)frmClasses.ActiveForm).txtMyTextBox.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;`. I'm not 100% sure on this syntax right now, though.

Comment: I was thinking more of placing the call in a class and calling it within the class:

Comment: Alright? have a `private frmClasses GetFormInstance()` method that does a `return frmClasses.ActiveForm`. Or (which is more OO-compatible), have a constructor in `ClsProperties` that takes a `frmClasses` as it's sole parameter. Then store it in there as a class member.

Comment: Why would you delegate a specific form's validation in another class? Looks circular and unnecessary to me. Unless there's a design you're trying to achieve not obvious from your code. I'm just trying to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: How do you access from controls from within a class.